# Problem with the Serializer for a Xslt2.0 transformation with Saxon

Tags: c#, xslt-2.0, saxon

This is my first try to program a Xslt2.0 transformation with SaxonHE 9.9 in C#, so the problem here is when I create the serilizer I get the error that the `class Saxon.Api.Serializer` contains no constractor with 0 arguments.

I know what this error means, but not why it occurs, cause each example that I see creates the serializer like this.. This question sounds a bit stupid, but I cannot find a answer to get it work.

```
using Saxon.Api;

namespace XY
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            String SourceFilename = "./test/test.xml";
            String StylesheetFilename = "./scripte/xml-to-html.xsl";
            String OutputFilename = "./Output/test.html";

            using (FileStream streamXml = File.OpenRead(SourceFilename))
            {
                using (FileStream streamXsl = File.OpenRead(StylesheetFilename))
                {
                    Processor processor = new Processor();

                    DocumentBuilder builder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();
                    Uri uri = new Uri("urn:test");
                    builder.BaseUri = uri;

                    XdmNode input = builder.Build(streamXml);
                    XsltTransformer transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(streamXsl).Load();

                    transformer.InitialContextNode = input;

                    Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
                    serializer.SetOutputFile(OutputFilename);
                    transformer.Run(serializer);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("test.html created successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
using System;
using Saxon.Api;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace XY
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

            String SourceFilename = ".\\test\\test.xml";
            String StylesheetFilename = ".\\scripte\\xml-to-html.xsl";
            String OutputFilename = ".\\Output\\result.html";

            if (StylesheetFilename.StartsWith(".\\"))
            {
                StylesheetFilename = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + StylesheetFilename;
            }

            if (SourceFilename.StartsWith(".\\"))
            {
                SourceFilename = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + SourceFilename;
            }

            var uri_source = new System.Uri(SourceFilename);
            var uri_xsl = new System.Uri(StylesheetFilename);


            Processor processor = new Processor();

            XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(uri_source);

            processor.SetProperty("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/preferJaxpParser", "true");

            XsltCompiler compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();

            XsltExecutable executable = compiler.Compile(uri_xsl);

            XsltTransformer transformer = executable.Load();

            transformer.InitialContextNode = input;

            Serializer serializer = processor.NewSerializer();

            System.IO.StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(OutputFilename);

            serializer.SetOutputWriter(stream);

            transformer.Run(serializer);

            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I change also some other thinks and now it works, thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll log a bug on the fact that there are sample apps and/or documentation that use the "new Serializer()" form.

We dropped this from the Java product in 9.8 because it caused constant trouble that the Serializer doesn't (necessarily) have access to all the configuration options (held in the Processor); also using a factory method `Processor.newSerializer()` potentially allows us to to create a subclass of `Serializer`, so it's more flexible. We then followed this pattern on .NET in the 9.9 release, partly for the same reasons, and partly because the .NET API has now been rewritten as a very thin layer on top of the Java API, which helps us to maintain commonality, and simplifies testing.

We try hard to maintain backwards compatibility in the main product APIs but it's not a requirement that overrides all others; if we feel that we got something badly wrong, then we fix it. As some people say to justify the policy, "the future is longer than the past".

**LATER**

We have done some checking and we think the 9.9 documentation and sample applications are correct; you must be using an older version. If I'm wrong, please identify the specific location where you found incorrect information.

Comment: In our application we used the Saxon 9he-api version 9.6.0.7 earlier and there was  public Serializer(); in the same but when we updated today to latest Saxon 9he-api version 9.9.1.5 the constructor has been removed and it breaks our code compilation now.
It should have been kept to support backward compatibility or provide the alternative please.

Comment: The alternative, as noted above, is to construct the serializer using the `Processor.newSerializer()` method. Sorry that you were inconvenienced by this change; I think I've explained the reasons it was made in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In 9.9 you can (or really need to) create a `Serializer` with the various overloads of `processor.NewSerializer` (see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/Processor.html#NewSerializer(Stream))..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for the problem:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Saxon.Api;

namespace Project1
{
    public static class ClassMain
    {
        public static string TransformXml(string xmlData, string xslData)
        {
            var xsltProcessor = new Processor();
            var documentBuilder = xsltProcessor.NewDocumentBuilder();
            documentBuilder.BaseUri = new Uri("file://");
            var xdmNode = documentBuilder.Build(new StringReader(xmlData));

            var xsltCompiler = xsltProcessor.NewXsltCompiler();
            var xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.Compile(new StringReader(xslData));
            var xsltTransformer = xsltExecutable.Load();
            xsltTransformer.InitialContextNode = xdmNode;

            var results = new XdmDestination();

            xsltTransformer.Run(results);
            return results.XdmNode.OuterXml;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var xmlData = File.ReadAllText("a.xml");
            var xslData = File.ReadAllText("a.xsl");

            var data = TransformXml(xmlData, xslData);
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```